# Used BufferedReader...Why this code doesn't work at android? It works in Java

Tags: android, bufferedreader, file-io

I wanted to set a array and input a word from txt file. (stage.txt)
It works in Java, but not in android...
When I use (System.out.println(stage[0][1]), the console showed String value.
But in Android, when I use

```
TextView show = new TextView; 
show= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question); 
show.setText(stage[0][1]);
```

The TextView showed nothing... what's wrong?... please help...

```
String[][] stage = new String[2][3];
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("stage.txt"));
for(int i=0; i<2;i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        stage[i][j]=in.readLine();
    }
}

in.close();
```

Comment: At DDMS in data/data/mapacage/files

Comment: try using the debugger -- you can see exactly what the strings are being set to and also see if setText() gets called with the string you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the TextView to the Layout you're using?
Or did you define the TextView in the layout XML-File? Then your code TextView show = new TextView; is wrong.

TextView show = new TextView; 
should be
**TextView show = new TextView(this);** (in an Activity).

Could you provide the full Code before?
What errors do you get?

UPDATE:
I'm wondering if your file is on your SD Card (because of that path). You can access the SD Card via Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() to get its root path.

For your projects, change that line to:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput("stage.txt")));
```

Full Source:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String[][] stage = new String[2][3];
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput("stage.txt")));
        for(int i=0; i<2;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
            {
                stage[i][j]=br.readLine();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    TextView question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    question.setText(stage[0][1]); 
}
```

Comment: I used/ show= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question); / My problem is there were no Sting at Sting[][] stage...

Comment: Do you get an error or is it just displaying nothing at all? Have you set setContentView(...) before? Where is your "stage.txt" located?

Comment: stage.txt is in SD Card...At DDMS in data/data/mypackcagename/files

Comment: Post the first 5 lines of your stage.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

//Assuming the 2d array is correctly filled
//if not  try putting the txt file in your asset folder and use getAssets()

but anyway
try doing it this way, see if it helps.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        question.setText(stage[0][1]);
    }
});
```